# cv.puttext overlapping using opencv and simple_facrec on yolov3

Tags: numpy, opencv, object-detection, yolo, face-recognition

I am using face recognition along with distance estimation but the output text for distance is overlapping. I am using **yolov3**. I am using these libraries.

```
import cv2 as cv
import NumPy as np
from simple_facerec import SimpleFacerec
```

here is my code of function.

```
# Load YOLO model
  ....code...
# Load COCO class names
....code...
# Open webcam
....code...
# Estimated camera calibration parameters
....code...
# Initialize SimpleFacerec
....code...


def display_results(img, boxes, confidences, classIDs, indexes, face_locations, face_names):
    font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX

    for i in indexes.flatten():
        x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
        label = classes[classIDs[i]]

        # Calculate distance using basic triangulation
        object_height = 500  # mm
        distance = (focal_length * object_height) / h #it calcilated in above code
        distance_cm = distance / 10
        #label_with_distance = f'{label}: {round(distance_cm, 2)} CM'

        # Display face recognition results
        for face_loc, face_name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            y1, x1, y2, x2 = face_loc[0], face_loc[1], face_loc[2], face_loc[3]

            if face_name:  # Check if face is recognized
                label_with_distance = f'{face_name}: {round(distance_cm)} CM'
                # Draw bounding box
                cv.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 250), 2)  # Blue color for recognized faces
                # Adjust y-coordinate to prevent overlap
                text_y = y1 - 10 if y1 - 10 > 10 else y1 + 40
                cv.putText(img, label_with_distance, (x1, text_y), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv.imshow("Combined Detection", img)

# Initialize frame count
....code...
# Main loop for video processing
....code...
# Read a frame from the webcam
....code...
# Break the loop if reading the frame fails
....code...
# Detect persons using YOLO
....code...
# Apply non-maximum suppression
....code...
# Face recognition using SimpleFacerec
....code...
# Display results
....code...
 # Check for user input to exit the loop
....code...
# Release resources
....code...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leald.png)

i tried alot of thing but the output is overlapping.The Output is also very laggy and slow.